# Is Observable from chained promises equivalent of observables created with from and chained with concatMap?

Tags: promise, rxjs, observable, dexie

I have an Angular app that have DexieDb / IndexedDb storage for objects selected from map. I always clear the db before adding new items. If the new items are same sometimes there can be constraint error:

selectionItemInfos.bulkAdd(): 1 of 1 operations failed. Errors: ConstraintError: Key already exists in the object store.

The error can be reproduced by calling method below repeatedly (in app double-clicking item as fast as possible):

```
  public setItemInfos(itemInfos: IItemInfo[]): Observable<number> {
    return from(this.db.selectionItemInfos.clear().then(() => {
      return this.db.selectionItemInfos.bulkAdd(itemInfos);
    }));
  }
```

However if I change the implementation to:

```
  public setItemInfos(itemInfos: IItemInfo[]): Observable<number> {
    const clear$ = from(this.db.selectionItemInfos.clear());
    const bulkAdd$ = from(this.db.selectionItemInfos.bulkAdd(itemInfos));

    return clear$.pipe(concatMap(() => bulkAdd$))
  }
```

I haven't been able to reproduce it.

I wonder if there something wrong with 1st implementation / have I assumed falsely that the table is cleared when bulkAdd is called OR is something wrong with the DexieDb / IndexedDb implementation (namely that it returns before it's really cleared)?

However my real question is: are the 2 methods supposed to be equivalent? I.e. have I just been lucky not been able to reproduce the error yet?

Comment: One difference is when the Promises are created. In the first example you create the second one after the first one resolves. In the second example you create both Promises beforehand, but I don't know if this could be causing your issue.

Comment: you mean Observables and not Promises? In 1st example there is only 1 Observable and 2nd there's 2 Observables.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm surprised that the second example isn't the one that produces the error.

```
const clear$ = from(this.db.selectionItemInfos.clear());
const bulkAdd$ = from(this.db.selectionItemInfos.bulkAdd(itemInfos));
return clear$.pipe(concatMap(() => bulkAdd$))
```

Just because you've wrapped the promise in **from** doesn't make it deferred.  So in this case **clear()** and **bulkAdd()** should start executing immediately and asynchronously, before the stream is setup.

The first version is better since the two calls should execute sequentially, but of course can fail if they are executed in rapid succession.  This is because you could have two calls of **clear()** execute, and then two calls of **blukAdd()** since the calls to **setItemInfos()** probably aren't getting waited for.

So both ways aren't right, and the only reason I could guess why second is less error prone is because **bulkAdd()** does have to wait until **clear()** is completely done and that the problem is just having two sequential executions of **bulkAdd()**.

The way to get your first implementation to work without error is to use **concactMap()** or **switchMap()** to prevent multiple simultaneous executions.  The difference between the two is that the latter will cancel prior executions when the next result is emitted from the higher level stream.

```
readonly setItemInfoSubject = new Subject<IItemInfo[]>();

private readonly doSetItemInfoSubcription = this.setItemInfoSubject.pipe(
  switchMap(itemInfos => this.db.selectionItemInfos.clear()
    .then(() = this.db.selectionItemInfos.bulkAdd(itemInfos)))
).subscribe();
```

Finally, In your second example there was not much point in wrapping the second promise with **from** since it was used inside an operator that accepts **ObservableInput**.  That type alias maps to the following types:  *Observable, InteropObservable, AsyncIterable, **PromiseLike**, ArrayLike, Iterable, ReadableStreamLike*.

Comment: Awaiting a promise multiple times just gives you the cashed value in the promise. It'll only ever resolve once. The first approach generates a new promise each time, the second doesn't. This explains why the second one doesn't error (but it likely isn't doing what the author wants).

Comment: setItemInfos(x).subscribe is called each time the doubleclick handler is called. i thought wrapping Promise to an Observable means that it behaves like an Observable

Comment: i can't understand how anything starts executing before I subscribe to the Observable returned by setItemInfos

Comment: @charm If you call a function, i.e. `this.db.selectionItemInfos.clear()`, then it's going to start immediately executing that - no matter what the function you're passing the result to does.  The answer, as always when you want to defer execution, is to provide a function instead. Check out [defer](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/defer), where you can wrap the call to the promise-producing function.

Comment: thanks! i found defer earlier today and it's doing what i thought from does.

Comment: @Daniel Gimenez : Care to explain the piece of code you added to your answer? Is it suposed to work like that I emit (with next) the itemInfos with the subject to the switchMap and eventually to the bulkAdd?

Comment: You've got it charm.  I've really gotten out of the habit of treating observables like promises and returning a new one.  It gets me into situations like the one you ran into.  In your case you've actually got a promise, so I don't see the point in creating an observable UNLESS you want to take advantage some additional functionality from rxjs like concatMap or switchMap and their ability to prevent simultaneous executions.

Comment: the thing with Observables is that this code is deep and everything above uses observables. the method calling setItemInfos also returns Observable and is combined to other Observables. it would be major change (at least I think so cause I'm total noob with Promises) to change the code to use Promises.

Comment: Then don't switch out your promises - it's okay.  It's just how I've been doing things and I like it.  What you do need to do is use a switchMap or concatMap at a higher level if you want those errors to go away.