# How to create a method that returns Observable that emits result of 2 Promises that need to be executed one after another?

Tags: promise, rxjs, indexeddb, dexie

I asked a question

[Is Observable from chained promises equivalent of observables created with from and chained with concatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70017028/is-observable-from-chained-promises-equivalent-of-observables-created-with-from)

on totally false premises. It seems that neither of my solutions had nothing to do with my intention.

I created a method that returns Observable and calls 2 methods returning Promise. I tried 2 ways:

```
  public setItemInfos(itemInfos: IItemInfo[]): Observable<number> {
    return from(this.db.selectionItemInfos.clear().then(() => {
      return this.db.selectionItemInfos.bulkAdd(itemInfos);
    }));
  }

  public setItemInfos(itemInfos: IItemInfo[]): Observable<number> {
    const clear$ = from(this.db.selectionItemInfos.clear());
    const bulkAdd$ = from(this.db.selectionItemInfos.bulkAdd(itemInfos));

    return clear$.pipe(concatMap(() => bulkAdd$))
  }
```

the use will be:

```
myService.setItemInfos(itemInfos).subsribe(count => {
  console.log(`Cleared the table 1st and then added ${count} new items`);
});
```

I thought from both versions that:

1. table clear is execution is finished when bulkAdd starts
2. when bulkAdd is finished i get the count from that in subscribe

How this should really be done? Or can it be done?

Comment: Is there any certain reason why you want to wrap promises into observables? Imperative actions like these normally compose easier using async functions (with await). I would be curious what gain Observables gives you in this case. When querying data (reading from db) on the other hand, Observables are great for observing readonly queries, which is the reason why Dexie 3.2 have them built-in using its new liveQuery() function.

Comment: unfortunately the reason is that I am Promise-illiterate and IMHO trying to get all this async / await stuff code to the app that works purely on Observables is not easy.

Comment: @DavidFahlander: I would appreciate an example how this is done with async await.

Answer (score 1):

This is (from what I can tell here), how I would do it.

In general, `defer` (or any higher-order operator) is a better way to create an observable from a promise. Defer lets you take the eager evaluation semantics of promises and turn them into the lazy evaluation semantics of observables.

Then all the usual observable operators and such will function as expected.

```ts
public setItemInfos(itemInfos: IItemInfo[]): Observable<number> {
  const clear$ = defer(() => this.db.selectionItemInfos.clear());
  const bulkAdd$ = defer(() => this.db.selectionItemInfos.bulkAdd(itemInfos));

  return concat(clear$, bulkAdd$);
}
```

---

#### Update 1:

So I think I might know what you're after. This isn't really idiomatic RxJS since it's such an interleaving mix of declarative, imperative style of code. Even so, this should work? I haven't tested it fully, but some tinkering and I think this should do what you're after.

There's most assuredly a better way to accomplish the same thing, but without seeing the bigger picture of what you're after, it's hard to say.

```ts
interface Tagged<T> {
  payload: T,
  tag: number
}

class abitraryClass{

  private setItemInfoSub: Subject<Tagged<IItemInfo[]>>;
  private processItemInfo: Observable<Tagged<number>>;
  private itemInfoTag = 0;

  constructor(){
    this.setItemInfoSub = new Subject<Tagged<IItemInfo[]>>();
    this.processItemInfo = this.setItemInfoSub.pipe(
      concatMap(({tag, payload: itemInfos}) => this.db.selectionItemInfos.clear().pipe(
        ignoreElements(),
        concatWith(defer(() => this.db.selectionItemInfos.bulkAdd(itemInfos))),
        map(response => ({
          payload: response,
          tag
        }))
      )),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
    // Make the processing pipeline live at all times.
    this.processItemInfo.subscribe();
  }

  public setItemInfos(itemInfos: IItemInfo[]): Observable<number> {
    const myTag = this.itemInfoTag++;

    this.setItemInfoSub.next({
      payload: itemInfos,
      tag: myTag
    });

    return this.processItemInfo.pipe(
      filter(({tag}) => tag == myTag),
      map(({payload}) => payload)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I actually tried ealier similar with defet but it was ```clear$pipe(concapMap(() => bulkAdd$)``` the problem with that was that it got mixed up when it was called multiple times before it was possible to finish.  with that version the error came really fast. i try this though

Comment: I know that my question doesn't specify that it needs to work also with multiple rapid calls so this might be qualified answer even if it doesn't fix my problem

Comment: concat is also deprecated AND return type of  ```concat(clear$, bulkAdd$)``` is Observable<void | number> so it doesn't build.

Comment: i tried and modified to  ```return concat(clear$, bulkAdd$).pipe(map(() => 0));```  but it resulted same error. however as said it might be correct answer to my question though.

Comment: I still don't think that's exactly what you want though. `concat(clear$, bulkAdd$)` will emit values from all of the input observables, whereas you only want the second one. Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-2jt5pi?devtoolsheight=60) to illustrate. Open the console to see what's happening.

Comment: @charm So I've made an update, it's not thoroughly tested, but you can try it and tinker a bit.

Comment: thanks. i'll have a look A.S.A.P.

Comment: sorry. i forgot to comment earlier but this doesn't build. i can't pipe the clear. also i have older rxjs in the app so no concatWith. However now i have time and I try to figure out the idea.

Comment: In older versions of RxJS concatWith is just called concat (there was a static and a pipeable version of concat, but noth had the same name). Also, I have no idea what 'pipe the clear' means.

Comment: 'pipe the clear' means that  this.db.selectionItemInfos.clear().pipe does not build. but ayway i appreaciate your help. i've sorted this now out using promises. i write my answer to here soone